# Access xampp with domain name on phone device on lan

Tags: mobile, windows-7, xampp, lan, domain-name

### Is it possible to acces to your Localhost xampp with domain name on phone device on lan?

I can access it on Computer with

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

inside of System32/drivers/etc/hosts

---

and some changes in xampp

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

inside of xampp/apache/conf/exstra/httpd-vhosts.conf

---

But is it possible to access it on phone device instead of writing my ip adress to the url bar?

I don't want applications like ngrok.com or others.

SPECS.: **Windows 7**, localhost port **:80**

### Thanks for response!